# show excerpt text on hover menu item of that page

Tags: jquery, wordpress

looking for away to bring in the page excerpt (short description) when rollover the main menu item of that page!

i will have a separate div out side the nav div which will fadein to show the excerpt text of that page and then fadeout….

i have the js to fade in on rollover but not sure how to bring in the text..

```
$("#menu-item-1266").hover(
  function () {
    $(".nav-excerpt").fadeIn('fast');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(".nav-excerpt").fadeOut('fast');
  }
);
```

Comment: Have a look at this http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/ or this http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/demos/

Comment: Thanks Joy, but i really need to know how to call the excerpt text  from the wordpress pages of each menu item ?

Comment: is the text you need within the div #menu-item-1266? what is the id of the div holding the text you need?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/sszmk/

Comment: See my solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/3vrjL/ and codes in my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Load excerpt for pages manually in .nav-excerpt by `echo my_get_post_excerpt( $post->ID );`

```
function my_get_post_excerpt($id)
{
   $content_post = get_post($id);
   return $content_post->post_excerpt;
}

echo my_get_post_excerpt( $post->ID );
```

so you should have something like this:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li id="menu-item-1266">Item 1266<li>
    <li id="menu-item-1267">Item 1267<li>
    <li id="menu-item-1268">Item 1268<li>
    <li id="menu-item-1269">Item 1269<li>
</ul>

<div class="nav-excerpt">
    <div rel="menu-item-1266"><?php echo my_get_post_excerpt( 1266 ); ?></div>
    <div rel="menu-item-1267"><?php echo my_get_post_excerpt( 1267 ); ?></div>
    <div rel="menu-item-1268"><?php echo my_get_post_excerpt( 1268 ); ?></div>
    <div rel="menu-item-1269"><?php echo my_get_post_excerpt( 1269 ); ?></div>
</div>

<script>
$("#menu li").hover(
  function () {
    $(".nav-excerpt div[rel="+$(this).attr('id')+"]").fadeIn('fast');
  }, 
  function () {
    $(".nav-excerpt div[rel="+$(this).attr('id')+"]").fadeIn('fast');
  }
);
</script>
```

Comment: this looks promising thanks.. how would this work if am using the WPML plugin on the site (languages) as the menu ids would change for each language page ?

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for your help the get_post_excerpt works but js isnt ? any idea why its not showing on rollover ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution using the qtip [tooltip] plugin. See http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/docs/ for docs.

CSS:

```
ul { margin: 20px; }
li { padding: 5px; float: left; border-left: 1px dotted #d0d0d0; background-color: green; }
li:hover { background-color: yellow; }
li a { color: white; text-decoration: none;  }
li a:hover { color: black; }

#excerpt { display: none; }
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a rel=".excerpt-1" href="#">Nav Item 1</a></li>
    <li><a rel=".excerpt-2" href="#">Nav Item 2</a></li>
    <li><a rel=".excerpt-3" href="#">Nav Item 3</a></li>
</ul>


<div id="excerpt">
    <div class="excerpt-1">EXCERPT 1 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="excerpt-2">EXCERPT 2 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
    <div class="excerpt-3">EXCERPT 3 - Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
</div>
```

--

Render your content inside #excerpt.

--

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu li a').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('rel');
        $(this).qtip({ 
            content: $(id).html(),
            style: { name: 'dark' }
        });
    });

    $('#menu li a').click(function() { return false; });
});​
```

--

Hope this helps. Working demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/3vrjL/